# Tools to Check Oracle database performance

Tags: java, database, performance, oracle, connection

I have an stand alone app which run several threads, for each thread there are a connection to the database, the business logic is to do some validations and send data to the database, it's too much information, about 2 millions rows in one hour.

So I need to know the database behaviour, the connections, sessions and everything, right know I'm using JVMonitor to check the app performance, now I need to check the database.

How can I check this? Is there a plug-in for Eclipse or anything like that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Toad session browser comes to mind. (Database->monitor->Session Browser)

Answer (score 2):

AWR and ASH reports along with v$ performance views. Integrated tools examples: Oracle Enterprise manager, method R and confio.